# allocation error in c++

Tags: c++

I have this following code to sort number which I read from text file. My text file elements must be like this:

```
3 6
6
5
1
```

The first number (3) in the first column represents the number of elements that should I sort, the first number in second column represent the max number which I have to send via array which is 6 here.

And the number must be sorted is `6 5 1`.

So this is my code but there is error says "invalid allocation size" and how to send max via array.

I need help please.

Here is my code:

```
 // Read and Sort.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std ;
#include<time.h>
#include <string>


int Max ;
int number_of_items;
const int s= 22;
int arr[s];
int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);



class sort{

public:


    int read_file()
    {
    int num = 0;
    int x ; 
    char filename[50];
    ifstream numbersfile ;
    cout<<"Please enter the file name below"<<endl<<"_______________________________________________"<<endl;

    cin.getline(filename,50);

    cout<<"_______________________________________________"<<endl;
    numbersfile.open(filename);

    if(numbersfile.is_open())
    {



    for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
        numbersfile>>arr[i];
        Max=arr[0];
        number_of_items=arr[1];
    }

    }
    else{
        cout<<"Failed To load requierd file"<<endl;
    }

    int arr2[s];
    cout<<"The elements supposed to be sorted are:"<<endl<<endl;
    for(int i =2;i<n;i++){
        numbersfile>>arr[i];
        cout<<arr[i]<<" "<<endl;

    }

      counting_sort(arr2,n);

    return 0 ;}


    int counting_sort(int arr[],int size)
        {

    int n=size;
    int max=arr[0];
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
        if (arr[i]>max) { 
            max=arr[i];
        }
    }

    int *output_array=new int[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        output_array[i]=0;
    }
    int *count=new int[max+1];
    for (int i=0;i<=max+1;i++) {
        count[i]=0;

    }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        count[arr[i]]=count[arr[i]]+1;
    }
    for (int i=1;i<max+1;i++) {
        count[i]=count[i]+count[i-1];
    }
    for (int  i=n-1;i>=1;i--) {
        output_array[count[arr[i]]-1]=arr[i];
        count[arr[i]]=count[arr[i]]-1;
    }

    cout<<"The sorted elements are:"<<endl<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cout<<output_array[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\n-----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    return 0;
}




};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     clock_t t1,t2;
     t1=clock();
     sort s1;
    s1.read_file();

    t2 = clock();
    float diff = ((float)t2 - (float)t1)/1000 ;
    cout <<"The time taken to execute this process is:\n"<< diff<<" Milliseconds." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of arrays

Comment: @NathanOliver i am still student and i don't how to use vectors

Comment: What is the line of the error?

Comment: @OiasBani Then this is a great opportunity for you to learn about them.

Comment: @Biffen looks like you are the one that added C as a tag...

Comment: i don't have a lot of time right now this is a task and i have a dead line please if there is any solution for this piece of code , put it here  thank you a lot

Comment: @OiasBani make sure you specify the exact error message along with identifying *which lines* it pertains to.

Comment: Can you show us the value of n? Try debugging it..

Comment: @crashmstr You're right. That was certainly not intentional. I think it might be due to a concurrent edit, though.

Comment: Why do you calculate the length of the array "arr" while you know it is 22?

Comment: n value is 21 as it calculated

Comment: dude do you see what have u written? ... U go in for loop 21 times

Answer (score 1):

```
int *count=new int[max+1];
for (int i = 0; i <= max+1;i++) {
    count[i]=0;

}
```

Note that here you goes out of range, because you try to access the last element as `count[max+1]`, because the `<=` in the conditional test, and this position is not allocated. It should be like this:

```
int *count=new int[max+1];
for (int i = 0; i < max+1;i++) {
    count[i]=0;

}
```

I suggest to you to carefully check each **for**, looking if you aren't accessing some position not bounded/allocated. Use printf's or cout's to debug, this is really useful.